# Characteristic polynomial of a specific matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

does anyone know how to solve this problem?

> Let $a_{0},\dots,a_{n-1}\in\mathbb{R}$ and let $n\geq2$. Prove that
> the matrix
> \begin{equation*}
>          A_{n} = 
>         \begin{pmatrix}
>              0&0&\dots&0&-a_{0}\\
>              1&0&\dots&0&-a_{1}\\
>              \vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots\\
>              0&0&\dots&1&-a_{n-1}
>          \end{pmatrix}
>      \end{equation*} has the following characteristic polynomial \begin{equation} p_{n}(\lambda) = (-1)^{n}\left(
>  \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a_{k}\lambda^{k}+\lambda^{n} \right). \end{equation}

Comment: Hint: Induction.

Comment: Thanks I'll try @azif00

Comment: I don't know the standard normal form definition of a matrix

Comment: The buzz-word is rational canonical form.